# Why isn't the legend in matplotlib correctly displaying the colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, line-plot

I have a plot where I am displaying 3 different lineplots. I am thus specifying the legend explicitly to display 3 colors, one for each of the plots. Below is a toy example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(1,20):
    if i%3==0 and i%9!=0:
        plt.plot(range(1,20),[i+3 for i in range(1,20)], c='b')
    elif i%9==0:
        plt.plot(range(1,20),[i+9 for i in range(1,20)], c='r')
    else:
        plt.plot(range(1,20),range(1,20), c='g')
plt.legend(['Multiples of 3 only', 'Multiples of 9', 'All the rest'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

But the legend does not display the colors correctly. Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390421/matplotlib-legend-not-working-correctly-with-handles), till then am also trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Rex5's answer; it works in this toy example, but in my actual plot (below) it was still producing wrong legends for some reason.

[image]

Instead, as suggested in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54390658/5305512) provided by Rex5, the following solution works (both in the toy example and in my actual plot), and is simpler too:

```
for i in range(1,20):
    if i%3==0 and i%9!=0:
        a, = plt.plot(range(1,20),[i+3 for i in range(1,20)], c='b')
    elif i%9==0:
        b, = plt.plot(range(1,20),[i+9 for i in range(1,20)], c='r')
    else:
        c, = plt.plot(range(1,20),[j for j in range(1,20)],c='g')
plt.legend([a, b, c], ["Multiples of 3", "Multiples of 9", "All of the rest"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I answered for the toy example as it was only mentioned(not the actual). Yet good that you find your solution !

Comment: @Rex5 Its weird why your solution does not work for my actual data.

Comment: You added the fourth `key:value` pair in the dictionary and added the `_nolegend_` clause in for loop ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_labels = {"x1" : "Multiples of 3", "x2" : "Multiples of 9","x3":'All of the rest'}

for i in range(1,20):
    if i%3==0 and i%9!=0:
        plt.plot(range(1,20),[i+3 for i in range(1,20)], c='b', label = my_labels["x1"])
        my_labels["x1"] = "_nolegend_"
    elif i%9==0:
        plt.plot(range(1,20),[i+9 for i in range(1,20)], c='r', label = my_labels["x2"])
        my_labels["x2"] = "_nolegend_"
    else:
        plt.plot(range(1,20),[j for j in range(1,20)],c='g', label = my_labels["x3"])
        my_labels["x3"] = "_nolegend_"
plt.legend(loc="best") #
plt.show()
```

Please see the `doc` link provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib/19386045#19386045) link, that would help with the answer explanation.